# Error when upload file with large size using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

It works when I upload files around 2MB, but error when I upload 2+MB files 
I have an application based on Laravel 5 with file upload functionality. 1. I try to insert images(jpeg,bmp,png) and files(Docx,xlsx,pdf) so Everything works fine when the size is arround 2MB 
but error when I upload 20+MB files Anyone know where the error?

my code

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        'proposition' => 'required',

    ];
    $filename = count($this->input('filename'));
    foreach(range(0, $filename) as $index) {
        $rules['filename.' . $index] = 'required|mimes:pdf,jpeg,bmp,png,doc,docx,csv,xlsx|max:20000';

    }
    return $rules;
}
```

my function

```
    public function store(PropositionRequest $request)
     {
    $proposition = new Proposition();
    $prop = Proposition::create($request->all());
    $prop->saveTags($request->get('tags'));
    foreach ($request->filename as $filename) {
        var_dump($filename);

        $filename = $filename->store('filename');
        PropositionFiles::create([
            'proposition_id' => $prop->num_proposition,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: Tell us the difference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914591/how-to-upload-some-file-pdf-using-laravel?

Comment: The default upload limit is 2mb, hence the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: i change th upload_max_filesize to 100 MB but  it still desn't work .. with the same error   ,                                                      
    FileNotFoundException in MimeTypeGuesser.php line 123:
The file "" does not exist

Comment: in addition to upload_max_filesize... also change post_max_size

Comment: i chage it too and nothing happened .. the same error :(